# How to get rows in pandas data frame, with maximal values in a column and keep the original index?

Tags: python, group-by, indexing, pandas, argmax

I have a pandas data frame. In the first column it can have the same value several times (in other words, the values in the first column are not unique).

Whenever I have several rows that contain the same value in the first column, I would like to leave only those that have maximal value in the third column. I almost found a solution:

```
import pandas

ls = []
ls.append({'c1':'a', 'c2':'a', 'c3':1})
ls.append({'c1':'a', 'c2':'c', 'c3':3})
ls.append({'c1':'a', 'c2':'b', 'c3':2})
ls.append({'c1':'b', 'c2':'b', 'c3':10})
ls.append({'c1':'b', 'c2':'c', 'c3':12})
ls.append({'c1':'b', 'c2':'a', 'c3':7})

df = pandas.DataFrame(ls, columns=['c1','c2','c3'])
print df
print '--------------------'
print df.groupby('c1').apply(lambda df:df.irow(df['c3'].argmax()))
```

As a result I get:

```
  c1 c2  c3
0  a  a   1
1  a  c   3
2  a  b   2
3  b  b  10
4  b  c  12
5  b  a   7
--------------------
   c1 c2  c3
c1          
a   a  c   3
b   b  c  12
```

My problem is that, I do not want to have `c1` as index. What I want to have is following:

```
  c1 c2  c3
1  a  c   3
4  b  c  12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `df.groupby(...).apply(foo)`, the type of object returned by `foo` affects the way the results are melded together.

If you return a Series, the index of the Series become columns of the final result, and the groupby key becomes the index (a bit of a mind-twister).

If instead you return a DataFrame, the final result uses the index of the DataFrame as index values, and the columns of the DataFrame as columns (very sensible).

So, you can arrange for the type of output you desire by converting your Series into a DataFrame.

With Pandas 0.13 you can use the `to_frame().T` method:

```
def maxrow(x, col):
    return x.loc[x[col].argmax()].to_frame().T

result = df.groupby('c1').apply(maxrow, 'c3')
result = result.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print(result)
```

yields

```
  c1 c2  c3
1  a  c   3
4  b  c  12
```

In Pandas 0.12 or older, the equivalent would be:

```
def maxrow(x, col):
    ser = x.loc[x[col].idxmax()]
    df = pd.DataFrame({ser.name: ser}).T
    return df
```

---

By the way, [behzad.nouri's clever and elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20703751/190597) is  quicker than mine for small DataFrames. 
The `sort` lifts the time complexity from `O(n)` to `O(n log n)` however, so it becomes slower than the `to_frame` solution shown above when applied to larger DataFrames.

Here is how I benchmarked it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit


def reset_df_first(df):
    df2 = df.reset_index()
    result = df2.groupby('c1').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['c3'].idxmax()])
    result.set_index(['index'], inplace=True)
    return result

def maxrow(x, col):
    result = x.loc[x[col].argmax()].to_frame().T
    return result

def using_to_frame(df):
    result = df.groupby('c1').apply(maxrow, 'c3')
    result.reset_index(level=0, drop=True, inplace=True)
    return result

def using_sort(df):
    return df.sort('c3').groupby('c1', as_index=False).tail(1)


for N in (100, 1000, 2000):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'b', 5: 'b'},
                       'c2': {0: 'a', 1: 'c', 2: 'b', 3: 'b', 4: 'c', 5: 'a'},
                       'c3': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 10, 4: 12, 5: 7}})

    df = pd.concat([df]*N)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

    timing = dict()
    for func in (reset_df_first, using_to_frame, using_sort):
        timing[func] = timeit.timeit('m.{}(m.df)'.format(func.__name__),
                              'import __main__ as m ',
                              number=10)

    print('For N = {}'.format(N))
    for func in sorted(timing, key=timing.get):
        print('{:<20}: {:<0.3g}'.format(func.__name__, timing[func]))
    print
```

yields

```
For N = 100
using_sort          : 0.018
using_to_frame      : 0.0265
reset_df_first      : 0.0303

For N = 1000
using_to_frame      : 0.0358    \
using_sort          : 0.036     / this is roughly where the two methods cross over in terms of performance
reset_df_first      : 0.0432

For N = 2000
using_to_frame      : 0.0457
reset_df_first      : 0.0523
using_sort          : 0.0569
```

(`reset_df_first` was another possibility I tried.)

Comment: It will work starting from [pandas 0.13](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5164), in older versions Series had no `to_frame` functionality.

Comment: @alko: Thanks for the head-up. I've added equivalent code which will work with version 0.12 or older.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df.sort('c3').groupby('c1', as_index=False).tail(1)
```

Comment: I can't force myself vote up pep8 violating code; yet to yield result desired by OP, you probably need to add `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`