# pandas groupby object index turns into FUBAR

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by

I have a pandas where my groupby operation turns the index into mush. I need the dates as my index, sorted within each ticker-group

To illustrate. Setup pandas like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

text = """Date   Ticker        Open        High         Low   Adj_Close   Volume
    2015-04-09  vws.co  315.000000  316.100000  312.500000  311.520000  1686800
    2015-04-10  vws.co  317.000000  319.700000  316.400000  312.700000  1396500
    2015-04-13  vws.co  317.900000  321.500000  315.200000  315.850000  1564500
    2015-04-14  vws.co  320.000000  322.400000  318.700000  314.870000  1370600
    2015-04-15  vws.co  320.000000  321.500000  319.200000  316.150000   945000
    2015-04-16  vws.co  319.000000  320.200000  310.400000  307.870000  2236100
    2015-04-17  vws.co  309.900000  310.000000  302.500000  299.100000  2711900
    2015-04-20  vws.co  303.000000  312.000000  303.000000  306.490000  1629700
    2016-03-31     mmm  166.750000  167.500000  166.500000  166.630005  1762800
    2016-04-01     mmm  165.630005  167.740005  164.789993  167.529999  1993700
    2016-04-04     mmm  167.110001  167.490005  165.919998  166.399994  2022800
    2016-04-05     mmm  165.179993  166.550003  164.649994  165.809998  1610300
    2016-04-06     mmm  165.339996  167.080002  164.839996  166.809998  2092200
    2016-04-07     mmm  165.880005  167.229996  165.250000  167.160004  2721900"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=1, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)
```

And the code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
import numpy as np
import time
import os

stocklist = ['vws.co','nflx','mmm']


print ('df.tail (Input df)\n',df.tail(6),'\n')


def Screener(group):

    def diff_calc(group):

        df['Difference'] = df['Adj_Close'].diff()
        return df['Difference']

    df['Difference'] = diff_calc(group)
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = GetStock(stocklist, start, end)
    df['Adj_Close'] = df['Adj Close']

    for ticker in stocklist:
        ### groupby screeener (filtering to only rel ticker group)
        df = df.groupby('Ticker', as_index=False).Adj_Close.apply(Screener)

    df.reset_index().sort(['Ticker', 'Date'], ascending=[1,1]).set_index('Ticker')
    print ('(Output df)\n',df,'\n')

# Test the first 7 rows of each group for rolling_mean transgress groups...
df_test = df.groupby('Ticker').head(7).reset_index().set_index('Date')
print ('df_test (summary from df) (Output)\n',df_test,'\n')
```

Apparently my index is now screwed up, and I do not know how this happened.

```
(Output df)
                   Ticker    Open    High     Low  Adj Close  Adj_Close        Date                                                               
0 0 0 2016-05-20  vws.co  443.00  446.30  441.40     442.90     442.90   
      2016-05-23  vws.co  442.00  446.70  439.90     439.90     439.90   
      2016-05-24  vws.co  439.10  450.00  438.10     450.00     450.00   
      2016-05-25  vws.co  455.50  466.10  454.30     464.90     464.90   
      2016-05-26  vws.co  465.00  470.80  464.60     464.60     464.60   
      2016-05-27  vws.co  464.00  480.70  461.20     476.00     476.00   
      2016-05-30  vws.co  477.00  481.80  473.10     475.00     475.00   
      2016-05-31  vws.co  474.00  479.30  472.20     479.00     479.00   
      2016-06-01  vws.co  477.40  480.20  472.90     474.40     474.40   
      2016-05-20    nflx   90.08   93.28   89.98      92.49      92.49   
      2016-05-23    nflx   92.98   95.29   92.85      94.89      94.89   
      2016-05-24    nflx   95.98   99.14   95.75      97.89      97.89   
      2016-05-25    nflx   99.00  100.31   98.30     100.20     100.20
```

**I need the dates as my index, sorted within each ticker-group**

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is this what you're after? `df['Difference'] = df.groupby('Ticker')['Adj_Close'].diff()`

Comment: I need the dates as my index, sorted within each ticker-group

Comment: Are the dates sorted in the input?

Comment: Yes the dates are sorted in the input to the groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK finally I found a solution. This line was my secret sauce

```
df = df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

This question helped me get the index back to how I wanted it. [How to get rows in pandas data frame, with maximal values in a column and keep the original index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703599/how-to-get-rows-in-pandas-data-frame-with-maximal-values-in-a-column-and-keep-t?rq=1)

Below code will rid me of the unwanted pr. iteration added col in the index. Thanks guys!

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
import numpy as np
import time
import os
from io import StringIO

text = """Date   Ticker        Open        High         Low   Adj_Close   Volume
    2015-04-09  vws.co  315.000000  316.100000  312.500000  311.520000  1686800
    2015-04-10  vws.co  317.000000  319.700000  316.400000  312.700000  1396500
    2015-04-13  vws.co  317.900000  321.500000  315.200000  315.850000  1564500
    2015-04-14  vws.co  320.000000  322.400000  318.700000  314.870000  1370600
    2015-04-15  vws.co  320.000000  321.500000  319.200000  316.150000   945000
    2015-04-16  vws.co  319.000000  320.200000  310.400000  307.870000  2236100
    2015-04-17  vws.co  309.900000  310.000000  302.500000  299.100000  2711900
    2015-04-20  vws.co  303.000000  312.000000  303.000000  306.490000  1629700
    2016-03-31     mmm  166.750000  167.500000  166.500000  166.630005  1762800
    2016-04-01     mmm  165.630005  167.740005  164.789993  167.529999  1993700
    2016-04-04     mmm  167.110001  167.490005  165.919998  166.399994  2022800
    2016-04-05     mmm  165.179993  166.550003  164.649994  165.809998  1610300
    2016-04-06     mmm  165.339996  167.080002  164.839996  166.809998  2092200
    2016-04-07     mmm  165.880005  167.229996  165.250000  167.160004  2721900"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=1, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)
runstart = time.time()     # Start script timer

stocklist = ['vws.co','nflx','mmm']#,'msft','tsla']
tickers =   []

def Screener(group):

    def diff_calc(group):

        df['Difference'] = df['Adj_Close'].diff()
        return df['Difference']

    df['Difference'] = diff_calc(group)
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for ticker in stocklist:
        ### groupby screeener (filtering to only rel ticker group)
        df = df.groupby('Ticker', as_index=False).Adj_Close.apply(Screener) #.reset_index()

        df = df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

    print ('(Output df)\n',df,'\n')

    # Test the first 7 rows of each group for rolling_mean transgress groups...
    df_test = df.groupby('Ticker').head(7).reset_index().set_index('Date')
    print ('df_test (summary from df) (Output)\n',df_test,'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The groupby function automatically sets the column you've grouped on as index. To avoid that pass the option: `as_index = False` in your groupby:

```
df_test = df.groupby('Ticker', as_index = False).head(7).reset_index().set_index('Date')
```

Comment: As you may see from my first groupby (iteration) I already do as_index=False. But it does not work as intended.  I get one empty index col pr ticker iteration...

Comment: ysearka - any ideas. I still get the new index col pr. ticker iteration. Even with the 'as_index = False' in the groupby...!

Answer (score 0):

The `diff` method of `GroupBy` objects keeps the dates as index:

```
# sort if needed (use 'mergesort' algorithm to preserve date order)
df = df.sort().sort_values('Ticker', kind='mergesort')

df['Difference'] = df.groupby('Ticker')['Adj_Close'].diff()
```

Note: if the input is not sorted, you need to sort it first. The code above sorts by index (i.e. dates) first, then by ticker using `mergesort` to preserve the dates' order.

**Output**

```
In [21]: df[['Ticker', 'Adj_Close', 'Difference']]
Out[21]: 
            Ticker   Adj_Close  Difference
Date                                      
2015-04-09  vws.co  311.520000         NaN
2015-04-10  vws.co  312.700000    1.180000
2015-04-13  vws.co  315.850000    3.150000
2015-04-14  vws.co  314.870000   -0.980000
2015-04-15  vws.co  316.150000    1.280000
2015-04-16  vws.co  307.870000   -8.280000
2015-04-17  vws.co  299.100000   -8.770000
2015-04-20  vws.co  306.490000    7.390000
2016-03-31     mmm  166.630005         NaN
2016-04-01     mmm  167.529999    0.899994
2016-04-04     mmm  166.399994   -1.130005
2016-04-05     mmm  165.809998   -0.589996
2016-04-06     mmm  166.809998    1.000000
2016-04-07     mmm  167.160004    0.350006
```

Comment: Thanks IanS, But I need the dates sorted UNDER each ticker group. I think your reply does not do that. Right?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, I think it does. Or do you want a multiindex with `Ticker` as level 0 and dates as level 1?

Comment: @Excaliburst you may not have been notified of my previous comment. Why don't you just run my code and see if it works for you? It works with the example you provided.

Comment: Thanks IanS, But I did - I get an error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'. And no I do not need multiindex just as your example shows with the added 'Difference' col to the df.

Comment: Hmm you must be using an older version of pandas. If you cannot upgrade, you can try `df = df.sort().sort('Ticker', kind='mergesort')`. See the (deprecated) [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html).

Comment: My pandas v. is 0.16. Thanks IanS

Comment: I still haven't been able to crack this one. Anyone out there that knows groupby like a champ?

Comment: Have you tried `sort` instead of `sort_values` like I suggested?

Comment: @Excaliburst (just in case you were not notified)